# NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey: attempt to insert non-property list object

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I think I'm doing something really obviously wrong here, but I can't figure it out! I'm attempting to save an NSMutableDictionary containing NSStrings and NSNumbers and NSBooleans into NSUserDefaults on iOS 7.1.

Here's the dictionary definition:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)hotLevelsDict
{
    if ( (!_hotLevelsDict) || ([_hotLevelsDict count] < 1) )
    {
        _hotLevelsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                          @{@100: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @50, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @200: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @100, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @500: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @200, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @1000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @200, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @2000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @500, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @5000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @10000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @20000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @10, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @50000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @100000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @200000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @300000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @400000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @500000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @600000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @700000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @800000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @20, @"points": @1000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @900000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @5, @"points": @50000, @"complete": @NO}],
                            @950000: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"time": @2, @"points": @50000, @"complete": @NO}]
                            }];
    }

    return _hotLevelsDict;
}
```

And saving it:

```
[defaults setObject:self.hotLevelsDict forKey:@"hotLevelsDict"];
```

I've tried printing the classes of all the sub objects within the dictionary, and they're all standard, also I'm doing the same thing to another dictionary constructed in a very similar way and it works fine.

Please could someone point out my error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a plist, the keys have to be strings. Since NSUserDefaults is backed by a plist, it enforces that restriction.

As a sidenote, I think it would be clearer for you to use `[@{...} mutableCopy]`.

Comment: Ah fantastic! Thanks! Also great tip with mutableCopy thank you :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you clarify as if it is possible to save a dictionary as an object to a string key with NSUserDefaults?

Comment: @techsavvy yes, you can have a dictionary as a value, but every key in that dictionary must also be a string.

Comment: @Kevin .. basically every key in that dictionary must have a value which is not of class NSNull Class. Any type of value can suffice I guess?

Comment: @techsavvy no, see the allowed types [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list). Basically, every key must be an NSString, and values can only be an NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSData, or an NSArray or NSDictionary, all objects inside of which must follow the same rules.

Answer (score 2):

The `NSUserDefault` only supports `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `BOOL`, `NSInteger`, `NSFloat` and other basic data types.

These collection types can still cause crashes if they contain other non - system data types. If you include a custom data type, you need to convert to `NSData` storage. [This is my test demo](https://github.com/githubbiao/NSUserDefault_study)